# Symfony 1.4 embedded form value lost upon saving on production server

Tags: symfony-1.4

I have a strange bug on a Symfony 1.4 project on the production server, while on the local server everything works fine. One form has multiple embedded forms and saving them works perfectly on local server (windows machine). While on the production server(linux), the embedded form value lost upon saving if there are more than 30 embedded forms. If there are less than 30 embedded forms, it also works fine. It is not a embedded form bug because it works fine on the local server. Both local and production server use symfony 1.4.19. I cannot figure out what causes the bug on the production server.

Debugging with var_dump($this->getValues), the value ['bookPrice']['price'] is null for some embedded forms, while the posted value is not null.

Comment: Have you compared the php.ini files? Could post_max_size be the problem? UPDATE: Nevermind, i just noticed you said that the posted values are fine, only the form values seem to have a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to clarify. Posted values are not correct. Post_max_size is the same. I found that the data was truncated. suhosin.request.max_vars was set to 100. This causes the problem. Set suhosin.request.max_vars = 1000 on php.ini resolves the problem.